# Gitignore switching environment

Tags: api, github, gitignore

I've put delicate things like API keys and login files in my .gitignore only to realise the obvious, that when i pull my project to another desktop, i miss these essential classes. Is there a way for me to hide information and still being able to have a project intact on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> still being able to have a project intact on GitHub?

Not directly after a git pull, since those sensitive data would *not* be in your GitHub repo (by design).

But what you *can* have in your GitHub repo is a *script*, able to query an outside source and fetch those data (after requesting credentials of sorts)

You then have *two* remote referential you are pushing data to:

- GitHub for your sources
- a vault of some kind (for instance [Hashicorp Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)), for your keys and other private data.

Comment: Smart, is that how it is done in 'real life' applications? It's pretty much work just to secure API key i think but if that's the only way.

Comment: @Gustavbang The one alternative I can think of is somehow embedding the sensitive data encrypted. But that will always be less secure than securing it in a separate referential.

Comment: Yeah, Hashicorp seems like a cool solution. I guess it is an appreciated skill, might be worth the time to get to know it.